# Auto reconnect to wifi once disconnected?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, usb

On Ubuntu 14.04, I am using a USB wireless adapter to connect to a wireless network. The connection is often disconnected (I have tried to solve the problem, but I don't know why. That is another question. See the output of `dmesg | grep wlan` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11053770/)).

My Network Manager sometimes can automatically reconnect, but sometimes it can't.

So when it disconnects, I often have to run

```
sudo dhclient -v wlan1
```

to reconnect. If that doesn't work, I will run

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B  -i wlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo dhclient -v wlan1
```

If that doesn't work, I will also reload its driver `rt2800usb` first:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800usb
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
sudo wpa_supplicant -B  -i wlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo dhclient -v wlan1
```

How shall we automatically run the commands every time it disconnects, i.e. make re-connection automatic?

There is a problem that [mostly the logic name for my USB adapter is `wlan1` but sometimes is `wlan0`.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615485/logic-name-of-my-usb-wifi-adapter-changes?s=1%7C0.0000)

Comment: What do you currently have in your **/etc/network/interfaces** ?
For the renaming, you might be able to disable this via the section "
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/
For the disconnections, that might probably be an issue with the driver, or maybe with your router. See e.g. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242033

My proposal would be to fix the cause of the disconnect/renaming, and not try to workaround the issue by reloading the driver.

Comment: `auto lo` and `iface lo inet loopback`. The usb adapter's driver only has one parameter `nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)`. My router works with WPA2 AES PSK, fixed channel 6.

Comment: I would like the answer to this as well :( I finally got my Wifi to auto-connect but it only connects @ boot.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the state of `wlan1` from `/sys/class/net/wlan1/carrier` , this is a sample script to check the state of your wifi interface every 2 seconds , then reconnecting ( replace `sleep 2` to check the connectivity every `n` seconds):

```
while true
     do
     i=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan1/carrier)
if [ $i == 1 ]
then
       echo "connected"

else
       echo "reconnecting"
       killall wpa_supplicant
       modprobe -rv rt2800usb
       modprobe -v rt2800usb
       wpa_supplicant -i wlan1 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
       dhclient wlan1
       echo "reconnected successfully"
       fi
sleep 2
done
```

**testing the script**

Run this script then open a new terminal and run `killall wpa_supplicant`, you will be reconnected again.

Comment: Do you mean `wpa_supplicant`?